# The id "constraintLayout" is not defined anywhere

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

Why new created constraintLayout does not have `android:id="@+id/constraint_layout_file_name"`?

After creating new constraintLayout we suppose to go to Design view and start creating our layout. But when we do so and we add to our layout for example a TextView, place it where we like and provide constraints so it stays like this after pushing layout on a device it will not stay where we want it to be. It will appear on left top corner on a device because constraints we provided have error

> The id "constraintLayout" is not defined anywhere.

What we have to do is to manually add `android:id="@+id/constraint_layout_file_name"` and edit all constraints. Example:

wrong constraint:

```
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
```

corect one:

```
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/constraint_layout_file_name"
```

Reason why I do ask is that it took me too much time to figure out what I'm doing wrong and I think I'm not the only one.

Comment: Enhance your question, it's difficult to understand what's you're asking

Comment: If you think that you are seeing a bug in Android Studio, [file an issue](http://b.android.com). We cannot help you with that.

Comment: Are you sure the root ID is even supposed to be there? It isn't in the CodeLab guide.  https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/constraint-layout/index.html#0

Comment: Meet the same problem

Comment: @cricket_007 the id "constraintLayout" is generated by the design editor. I meet the same issue and don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem.
and when i turned on the Autoconnect (on the top | left side) it fixed it by changing it
from:

```
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
```

to:

```
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
```

Comment: Not in constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha2. Now after update there is no problem.

Answer (score 0):

first,`compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta4'`;
second,sync your project!